# UIImage imageNamed: name returns nil the second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have this piece of code I use to test animations in iOS. The goal is to load 4 png's and animate them in an `UIImageView`. I have an `NSMutableArray imageNames` in which I keep the paths to the images. It gets filled correctly. Then when I try to use it to create `UIImage` it works the first time, but it returns nil afterwards. Why does this happen? I can't wrap my head around this.

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
    NSString *name = [imageNames objectAtIndex:i];
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:name]];
}
```

Here's the full code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *test = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 50, 50)];
    test.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [self.view addSubview:test];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    NSMutableArray *imageNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

    NSString *basePath = @"/Users/johndoe/Desktop/soa/SoA/SoA/Models/firefly/";
    // Load images
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        NSMutableString *fullPath = [NSMutableString stringWithString:basePath];
        [fullPath appendFormat:@"SMALL_0000_Capa-%ld.png", i + 1];
        [imageNames addObject:fullPath];
//        [fullPath appendString:@"SMALL_0000_Capa-1.png"];

    }

    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
        NSString *name = [imageNames objectAtIndex:i];
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:name]];
    }

    // Normal Animation
    UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 95, 86, 193)];
    animationImageView.animationImages = images;
    animationImageView.animationDuration = 0.5;

    [self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
    [animationImageView startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: The `UIImage imageNamed:` only takes a base filename - no path, no extension. The named image should be an image found in your app's resource bundle. Why are you passing a full path? Why are you hardcoding a path on your computer for an iOS app? All of this is wrong.

Comment: I would imagine it's wrong, but it's for testing purposes, since I don't have any experience with iOS. So for now I'm just trying to show something on the screen. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you said that it's for learning purposes I've tried your code and the only real problem I found is the one pointed by @rmaddy. I don't know where your image is stored exactly but I tried it adding 4 images as Assets and changed your code from this:

```
NSString *basePath = @"/Users/johndoe/Desktop/soa/SoA/SoA/Models/firefly/";
// Load images
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    NSMutableString *fullPath = [NSMutableString stringWithString:basePath];
    [fullPath appendFormat:@"SMALL_0000_Capa-%ld.png", i + 1];
    [imageNames addObject:fullPath];
}
```

to this:

```
// Load images
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pos%i", i];
    [imageNames addObject:path];
}
```

and I think it worked as you expected.

Comment: I found my mistake. It was very stupid :D. I didn't see that my images had different names. I chose your answer as best, for telling me to use assets, which i didn't know nothing about.

Comment: If those images will be static (will be provided with your app) then I would recommend those to be in Assets. Another approach, if you will download the images from somewhere over the internet, is to save the image in some of your app's directory (like Document) and load it from there. You can read more from here: [Working with Directories on iOS](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Directories_on_iPhone_OS#Identifying_the_Documents_Directory)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your

```
animationImageView.animationImages = images;
```

by this method:

```
[animationImageView setAnimationImagesWithUIImageViewSize:images];
```

This solution is provided by using this category: [UIImageView+AnimationImages.m](https://github.com/joandome/iOS-Utils/blob/master/UIImageView%2BAnimationImages.m)

Comment: I didn't test this solution yet. :]

Comment: Ok, I will try this, but nevertheless it throws error when I try to add new image in images: 'object cannot be nil'. So i don't even get there in the first place. The interesting thing is that the new image is null when i = 1, but not when i = 0, from where my confusion arose.